# What is the best way to call API for each data in the list/tuple in python?

Tags: python

I have a tuple with t = (10,20,30).
I want to call an API for each of the member of this tuple t.
Obviously, I can loop and call API - f("hello", b,10), f("hello",b,20),
f("hello",b,20)  for each item in the tuple.

However, I am looking for a best way to do this in Python.

I want to use map here or lambda. How can I do so?

How do I map with some default parameters?

Comment: You've already mentioned the best way - for loop.

Comment: The answer depends on what you want the result to be. If you want, for example, a single value, then .reduce is the right option. If you want to work each value independently, then .map is the best option. If you want to discard data, then .filter and so on. What do you need to do to the tuple?

Comment: @PrawnHongs: One question you've asked is "How do I map with some default parameters". Wouldn't that depend upon the implementation of the API function that you're calling? If the function is implemented to use default values for any arguments that you don't supply, it will work. I suspect you actually intended to ask some other question (perhaps about keyword args). Pls clarify.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to an explicit loop is `map`:

```
tuple(map(f, t))

# or

list(map(f, t))
```

This also opens the possibility to use thread or process pools for larger tasks.

Answer (score 0):

With a for loop it's for example

```
for a in t:
    f("hello", b, a)
```

The list comprehension gives you a list as a result, which may not be what you expect:

```
[ f("hello", b, a) for a in t ]
```